# Is this possible Each inserts returned id Update another table

Tags: mysql, strapi, mysql-8.0

I'm merging 4 tables (com_app, com_system, com_platform,com_service) into 1 table (product)
using this ***sql***

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO product(fields...)
  SELECT (fields...) from (com_app);
```

but there is 5 related table left (upload_file_morph,com_apps__teches...)
its example  field is
example

***upload_file_morph*** related to ***upload_file***

```
id |upload_file_id |related_id |  related_type|      field
 1 |        835 |         1 |       com_app| coverPhoto
 2 |        836 |         1 |    com_system| coverPhoto
```

***com_apps__teches*** related to ***teches*** table

```
id | com_app_id |  tech_id |
 1 |        835 |        1 |  
 2 |        836 |        1 |
```

1 first get source tables **com_app** data id **x** then

2 in **product** get new inserted id **y**

3 find and update ***upload_file_morph*** table using **x** like this

```
UPDATE upload_file_morph
 SET related_id = [y]
 WHERE related_type='com_app' AND field='coverPhoto' AND related_id=x;
```

final expectation is like

```
 every insert y =
 INSERT IGNORE INTO product(fields...)
  every data x= {SELECT (fields...) from (com_app)}
 update on every insert
 { UPDATE upload_file_morph
    SET related_id = [y]
    WHERE related_type='com_app' AND field='coverPhoto' AND related_id=x
 }
```

database structure is because  [Strapi](https://strapi.io/)  database

Comment: You may perform all queries inside a single transaction.

Comment: Use a `SELECT` query with `JOIN` in the `INSERT` query.

Comment: Or maybe what you need is `UPDATE` with `JOIN`. The question isn't clear on whether you're creating new tables or updating existing tables.

Comment: Is there something in the `product` table that relates the original table and ID to the new ID?

Comment: no if such query works original table no longer use will deleted

Comment: So how will you find the new ID y from the original ID x?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the `product` table has columns `original_type` and `original_id`, so you can see what the ID replacements are. Replace these in the query below with the actual columns that serve this purpose.

```
UPDATE upload_file_morph AS u
JOIN product AS p on p.related_id = u.original_id
SET related_id = u.id
WHERE u.original_table = 'com_app'
AND p.related_type='com_app' AND p.field='coverPhoto'
```

If you don't have columns that relate the old and new IDs, I don't think you'll be able to solve this.